# Convert SQL Row to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How would you convert a field that is store as multiple rows into columns?

Current data:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3
----------------
TEST  30    NY
TEST  30    CA
TEST2 10    TN 
TEST2 10    TX
```

I would like the output to be :

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
------------------------
TEST  30    NY    CA
TEST2 10    TN    TX
```

Comment: With a PIVOT function usually.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: Search for pivot. E.g.,: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: JUan Carlos. SQL Server

Comment: is it possible to have different values for `COL2` for the same `COL1`? i.e `TEST 30 NY` and `TEST 20 CA`? If that's the case, what is your expected results?

Answer (score 1):

based on your sample data, you can try this. no need to use pivot.

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       MIN(col3) col3,
       MAX(col3) col4
  FROM table
 GROUP BY col1,
          col2
```

Comment: Yes, with the sample data this will work but not if there are 3 or more rows with the same col1 and col2.

Comment: i know. i can use row_number() for situation where there would be more than 2 rows for each col1 and col2 but the logical solution still needs to be determined which should be in col3 and col4.